# regarding ardunio error

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-nano

Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Uno"

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\bin../lib/gcc/avr/7.3.0/../../../../avr/bin/ar.exe: unable to rename 'core\core.a'; reason: Permission denied

exit status 1

Error compiling for board Arduino Uno.

continue error is coming having downloading over more than 15 times. How can i overcome this problem

Comment: Have you tried turning off your antivirus software for a single compilation? Described in [this issue on github](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/6758)